# EasyMock - Spring taking the original object not the mocked object

Tags: unit-testing, junit, easymock, spring-test

While testing my Spring classes with EasyMock, I came to this below scenario:
My Spring configuration is taking the original DAO object configured by Spring `component-scan` rather than my mock DAO object.

Please find my mock, AppContext and test class below:

ApplicationContxt-Test.xml

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.testclasses"/>
<import resource="mockServices.xml" />
```

MockServices.xml

```xml
<bean class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock"
    id="codeDAO" primary="true" >
    <constructor-arg value="com.test.testclasses.dao.MaintainCodeDAO" />
</bean>
```

JUnit class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:ApplicationContxt-Test.xml")
public class MaintainCodeServiceImplTest {
    @Autowired
    private MaintainCodeDAO codeDAO;

    @Autowired
    private MaintainCodeService maintainCodeService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        EasyMock.reset(codeDAO);
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        EasyMock.reset(codeDAO);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAutowireDependencies() {
        assertNotNull(codeDAO);
        assertNotNull(maintainCodeService);
    }
    @Test
    public void getProcedureByCode_success() throws Exception {

        MaintainCodeVO maintainCodeVO = new MaintainCodeVO();
        EasyMock.expect(codeDAO.searchProcedureCode(isA(String.class))).andReturn(maintainCodeVO);
        EasyMock.replay(codeDAO);

        MaintainCodeBO maintainCodeResult = maintainCodeService.getProcedureByCode("test"); 
        EasyMock.verify(codeDAO);
        codeDAO.searchProcedureCode("test");
        assertNotNull(maintainCodeResult);
        EasyMock.reset(codeDAO);

    }
}
```

Here I am mocking `codeDAO` and while testing the service class, instead of the mock `codeDAO`, the original DAO object is getting autowired and `EasyMock.verify()` is throwing exception. Don't know whats the issue. Is there any problem with the above configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The trick was so simple .. I killed one day finding the solution..
So here is the solution:

Just move the mockServices.xml (spring xml with only mock configurations) above context:component-scan...

```
    <import resource="mockServices.xml" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wellpoint.icnotes"/>
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, because of `createMock` is a generic method, the Spring doesn't work properly while inferring the bean type, it infers it as an `Object`, so it cannot wire. I suggest not to use the Spring in unit tests, use simple classes.

BTW, EasyMock has it's own DI, just use it: http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-annotations

It is possible to put mocks into context, e.g. as described here: [Autowiring of beans generated by EasyMock factory-method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340007/autowiring-of-beans-generated-by-easymock-factory-method) but for me it is not the best approach, looks clumsy.

Comment: Yea we can do that..As u said it looks too clumsy. I need to write unit test cases for more than 100 service classes and this doesn't seem to be a good idea. I have done this before and don'y know why it is not working now.....

Comment: @ArunRaj I prefer injections by EasyMock/Mockito DI. No spring - works faster, looks better, less dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Spring Framework 4.2 or higher, this should work. See the following related issues for details.

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9567
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9682
- [Is there any way to override a bean discovered by component scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972824/is-there-any-way-to-override-a-bean-discovered-by-component-scan)