# context:component-scan where modify value

Tags: java, spring, eclipse-jee

I have a problem of component-scan :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.example" />
```

I want modify (or override) existing configuration but i don't know where i can modify the default value

Comment: What is the default value? What it the new expected value? What is the project structure? Why don't you simply rewrite the value?

Comment: To override a specific bean/class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972824/is-there-any-way-to-override-a-bean-discovered-by-component-scan

Comment: I don't found the default value, but i want change or add my value. Rewrite why not but i don't know the file i have to change

Answer (score 0):

You should understand **@Configuration** and **@EnableAutoConfiguratiom**

**@Configuration** is an analog for xml file. Such classes are sources of bean definitions by defining methods with the @Bean annotation.

**@EnableAutoConfiguratiom** can be used with or without @Configuration. It tells Spring to set up some basic infrastructure it depends on what you have in the classpath.

More you can find e.g here :

[Spring configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html)